# What should be included in an extended abstract (CS)

Tags: abstract

I've been tasked with writing an extended abstract. I'm studying computer science (CS) and I have had a look online for an idea of what an extended abstract should contain.

So far, I gather that it should contain roughly 1000 words, excluding graphs, diagrams and references. It also appears that it should contain an introduction, and some preliminary results as well as address the `what`, `why` and `how` questions.

I was wondering, could someone provide me with a bullet-point-style breakdown of what an extended abstract needs to contain?

As an example of what I mean, here is how I would break down an abstract:

1. Define the topic
2. Describe the problem that the topic is facing
3. State why this research is important and what it provides
4. Describe the main contribution of the paper and summarise the conclusion
5. Describe future avenues of research

Comment: Is 5 typical in CS?

Comment: @kimball the number of points it took to list my personal breakdown of an abstract just happend to require 5. It's an example.

Comment: For an extended abstract, you can omit 1.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-write-an-extended-abstract

Comment: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1351/what-is-an-extended-abstract

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content may include the following, some of which may overlap with the points you have mentioned already.

- Definition and scope of the topic
- The problem you are to focus on the topic
- If the problem was faced before, describe the state of the art.
- If you are introducing the problem, express the importance of it.
- Discuss the methods and novel techniques to be employed
- Highlights of the results obtained
- Possible future enhancements and further work in progress

Some extended abstracts also allow the use of references, consult with the publisher/conference committee for any clarifications.

The extent of explanation on the above points is confined to the constraint of the maximum length prescribed by the publisher/conference committee you wish to submit to.

Comment: Some journals/conferences limit the main body to a single page...