# Is it worthy to publish an extended abstract in a conference?

Tags: publications, conference, computer-science, abstract

I have an accepted Extended abstract in an international conference. As a master student, it is heavy to pay for an extended abstract (400 Euros ).  But at the same time is it good for my future to publish an extended abstract ( 2 pages paper ) in a conference?

Comment: I don't think this is something we can judge; we don't know you, your future career plans, the quality of the abstract, or the quality of the conference. You should speak to faculty in your department, who may be better positioned to advise you on this.

Comment: Conference name : ICITST . I have a plan to study Phd .

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that if you tell us those details, we'd be able to answer this. I think this question is simply not answerable by strangers on the Internet. Speak to faculty in your department. (If you plan to do a PhD, you anyways need to form relationships with faculty in your department, who will hopefully then be able to write recommendation letters for you.)

Answer (score 0):

The aspect of what an extended abstract is differs from one field to another. Refer this page to get a better idea on what does it mean in your field:

[What is an extended abstract?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1351/what-is-an-extended-abstract)

For example, in [CVPR](http://www.pamitc.org/cvpr15/extended_abstracts.php), 
extended abstracts are handed out to the attendees before the start of the conference. They are much more handy than a huge proceedings book as each article is much smaller than its full version and includes all relevant details at a glance. It serves as a means to attract attendees attention especially when there are multiple venues occurring in the same time.

However, whether the amount you pay for it worth it or not depends on various factors, such as the field, the tier of the conference and so on. Sometimes in top tier conferences, there may be funding agencies who might be attending the conference. In such cases extended abstract would be a pretty valuable. But in any case, this decision would be better sought out by consulting it with your advisor or faculty members of your department as @ff524 suggested.